# Azure AD sign on using email and password in console app

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, console-application, microsoft-graph-api

I have tried in web application oAuth2 with AD. So when user visit my page he will be redirected to Microsoft login page once he logged in he will have access to my application.

How can we achieve this in console app. When my console app starts how can I make user sign in browser and then get token in the console app after successfully  login?

Answer (score 1):

I found a sample program maybe it will help

https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2

[Here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-Tokens#token-acquisition-methods) you can see methods to do what you wanted.

With the code below after executing a window will prop for the user to login or choose account to use.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
var app =new PublicClientApplication("YOUR_CLIENT_ID");
var accounts = app.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes).Result;
```

Comment: Apparently I thought this was a site for people to help each other, getting a little help was better than getting no help at all.

Comment: Sure it is. I'm not talking about your answer exactly (because it is actualy helpfull and looks like an answer after your last edit) and I'm also not downvoting it. But as I said before - there is a [reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) why you can't leave a comment with less then 50 rep.